# Error while trying to parse running processes through Python

Tags: python, subprocess

I made an attempt at parsing running programs in my computer (Debian OS) with the Subprocess python module. Here is my code:

```
import subprocess

cmd = "ps -A" # Unix command to get running processes

runningprox = subprocess.check_output(cmd) #returns output as byte string

rpstring = runningprox.decode("utf-8") 
#converts byte string to string and puts it in a variable

print(rpstring)
```

However, when I run the code, I get the following error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "ratalert.py", line 6, in
>   
>       runningprox = subprocess.check_output(cmd) #returns output as byte string   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 336, in
>   check_output
>       **kwargs).stdout   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 403, in run
>       with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 707, in **init**
>       restore_signals, start_new_session)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1333, in _execute_child
>       raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg) FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ps -A'

I don't understand why I get this error message. Considering 'ps -A' is neither a file nor a directory, but just the Unix command I put in a variable as a string.

How can I fix this? Thank you.

Comment: Actually `ps` **is** a file, try using `/bin/ps -A`

Comment: @gogaz just tried it but I get the same error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `subprocess.check_output` function expects a list with the command and its arguments, like so:

```
runningprox = subprocess.check_output(['ps', '-A'])
```

Otherwise, it will treat the string you passed as a single command, and will look up for an executable file with name `ps -A`, space included and all.

You can use shlex to do the splitting as the shell would do:

```
import shlex, subprocess

cmd = 'ps -A'
runningprox = subprocess.check_output(shlex.split(cmd))
```